# Durandal/Require: module load and execution

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

In a shell whit a navbar I have to call javascript function (external module) but only when the composition is completed.

This is my code:

shell.js

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'charms'], function (router, app, ch) {
  return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        router.map([
            { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
            { route: 'Gallery', moduleId: 'viewmodels/gallery', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    }
  };
});
```

I was trying to use attached/compositionComplete callback but the module is call always before.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Which external module are you trying to load? What is it doing?

Comment: Nothing special… it add a charms bar to the page. Maybe I didn't understand something, but I wonder why the module is called before activate and compositionComplete or attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Brett's answer. If charms is a valid AMD module, but it executes immediately when loaded than you shouldn't declare it as dependency. Instead `require` it when needed. In order to do so change the require syntax to commonjs style http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar.

```
define(function (require) {
  var router = require('plugins/router'),
      app = require('durandal/app')        

  return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        router.map([
            { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
            { route: 'Gallery', moduleId: 'viewmodels/gallery', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    },
    attached: function(){ // or compositionComplete whatever suits better
        require('charms');
    }
  };
});
```

**Please note** Based on your description above this `charms` executes immediately when loaded, but AMD modules are only evaluated once during the life time of an application. So you might want to return something like a `init` or `run` function from `charms`, so that it can be executed multiple times.

#### Hypothetical charms

```
define(function (require) {
  function init(){
      //do whatever charms is doing
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
});
```

That way you wouldn't have to switch to the commonjs style and could simply call

```
attached: function(){ // or compositionComplete
    ch.init()
}
```

Comment: Or define the `charms` module as a constructor function or a factory function (as opposed to a singleton), and instantiate when needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not provided a `compositionComplete()` or `attached()` method to the returned viewmodel. Durandal executes these functions on your viewmodel, **if** they exist. You can read about it here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/. So, add them, like this:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'charms'], function (router, app, ch) {
  return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        // this is called when the shell module is activated (always called FIRST)
        router.map([
            { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
            { route: 'Gallery', moduleId: 'viewmodels/gallery', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    },
    attached: function() {
        // this is called when the shell view is attached to the DOM
    },
    compositionComplete: function () {
        // this is called when the shell view composition is complete
    }
  };
});
```

If the code in your `'charms'` module is executed before any of the activator methods, it's probably because it wasn't written in the modular pattern that works with RequireJS. You must wrap modules with a `define()` for them to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry Brett, but I didn't include attached and/or compositionComplete method in the code box because I wanted to highlight how framework works. I have to understand better about AMD.  Many thanks